# create compiled executable for sklearn model in unix

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'd like to be able to train a model in Python using scikit-learn, and then save this model to disk in such a way that it is now a binary compiled executable.

Ideally, for example, it could be a classifier called by doing something like the below in a unix shell, feeding in a feature vector, and returning a class label.

```
$ ./model 2 1 2 1.5 3 2 5 0 1
-1
```

Since much of scikit-learn is wrapped C, I hoped this would be possible.

Is it possible to create a model in sklearn, persist it, and embed the model in an executable?

Comment: This is a legitimate question, there's no need for downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

No need to write a C program for that, you can just write a Python command-line script to parse the commandline argument, call a model and output the prediction on stdout. I you want to parse complex commandline argument options you can use: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Render the script executable and put it in your PATH and you are done.

> Since much of scikit-learn is wrapped C, I hoped this would be possible.

This is not very true. Most of scikit-learn is Python code + compiled extensions written in Cython. We also wrap 2 small C++ libraries (libsvm and liblinear). But there is no public C API to link against.

If you are really interested in freezing scikit-learn to make it independent from the system Python and the numpy, scipy dependencies by embedding everything in a standalone binary folder you can try to use cx_Freeze or the likes but this can be complicated.

Comment: Yes, I could but I'm very interested in speed. Simply calling a python script involves loading the model (maybe from pickle is fastest?) and then evaluating in Python. This is why I'd like a fast, compiled C version. Maybe it is a better question to ask how I might do this to get the best performance.

Comment: It depends on the actual speed requirements you have. See http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/computational_performance.html . The overhead of a Python function call is less than a microsecond. The overhead of starting a Python interpreter and importing sklearn is ~400ms. Loading a model from the disk and extracting the features for the new data is likely to dominate any Python-related overhead. Any why if you don't want to rely on the python interpreter at all, don't use scikit-learn. Use sofia-ml or vowpal wabbit for instance.